# Correcting a Regexp for identifying URLs in plain text

Tags: c#, regex

I have been using the following regular expression to find urls in a plain text file so that I can convert them to HTML links.

```
const string pattern = @"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)";
```

This seems to work fine except for when there is an '#' in the URL. So for the this URL

```
 http://www.example.com/ckm/OKM.html#showarchetype_1013.1.868_7
```

the URL identification stops at the '#'

Any ideas which part of the regexp needs to change so as to identify the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#` inside the second character class from the end.

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w_-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_#]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oZ2eE7/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w_#-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)

                                                                                                                        ^^
```

Try this.See demo.Added `#` above.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/3